# api.ai webhook authentication

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-home

I've successfully completed account linking on api.ai, and now I'm trying to execute a webhook. The problem here is that I need the token that was generated during the linking process to go into the authentication field. Otherwise I will always get a "403" error back. How can you change the auth token in the webhook header field dynamically for each user that issues a Google Home voice command?

Comment: can you tell me how you  achieved the linking of authentication ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all I know that's not currently possible. I pretty much had the same issue, and I resorted to connecting to an intermediate server that handles the webhook, extracts the access token (available via the actions-on-google node.js API as getUser().access_token), and then forwards the request in the right format to the original host.

Comment: Thats a bummer. Hopefully that changes soon.

Comment: what do you mean by getUser().access_token? I can see in parameters something like https://gist.github.com/igorkasyanchuk/aa4adae4614ccdac3c7464100f68877a. Do you have in your app all user_ids? (like here slack_user_id or recepient.id for facebook?